# Symfony Role management and permissions

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem. I'm making a new application with Symfony (6) and ApiPlatform (2.8).

I need to make an access system with roles and permissions on my users.

A role gives access to several permissions and a user can have additional permissions.

Therefore, I have a "User" entity which has a "role" attribute of type relation on the "Role" table which defines all possible roles.

I also have a "Permissions" table that defines the possible permissions.

A "RolePermissions" table that defines the possible permissions according to the role.

A "UserPermissions" table that will contain the possible permissions complementary to a user.

Now, I want to use "is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")" from Symfony. But is_granted() uses the role field of type string. As I have a relationship, how can I check the accesses?

I would like to secure my API routes.

```
#[ApiResource(

    collectionOperations: [

        'get' => [

            'security' => 'object == user or is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")',

        ],

        'post' => [

            'security' => 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")',

        ])]
```

Do I need to create a special system?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Strictly speaking the Symfony authorization system relies on UserInterface::getRoles() returning any array of string roles.  How you actually store the roles in the database is irrelevant.  You just need to have getRoles return the desired information.  Possibly with a custom user provider.  Depends in part on what you mean by `permissions` and how they relate to roles.

Comment: The roles would be for example "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_DEVELOPER", "ROLE_MEMBER". These roles would be linked to permissions like "PERMISSION_VIEW_PAGE_USERS", "PERMISSION_EDIT_PAGE_USERS". So roles would be in MANY_TO_MANY (A role can have several permissions and a permission can be in several roles). I know that for Symfony, roles are directly permissions, but in my case, I can't do what Symfony advises in the documentation.
Maybe my getRoles() function was badly done and doesn't get the string. I don't have my code in front of me.
The user provider, I don't see how it could help?

Comment: Hmmm.  Ultimately isGranted can only deal with roles.  So you might have a `ROLE_VIEWER_PAGE_USERS` and `ROLE_EDITOR_PAGE_USERS`. You can do some database linking such that anyone with a `ROLE_ADMIN` is automatically assigned the preceding two roles as well.  I'm guessing you might end up with quite a few role types but that by itself is no problem.  The user provider suggestion would allow you to generate an user's final list of roles by kicking off queries and maybe doing some other processing.  As opposed to a custom voter which would do something similar each time isGranted is called.

Comment: Okay. I think I understand what you're saying. You want me to keep the "role" attribute of my "user" entity in string type and I would have in my database field ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_VIEWER_PAGE_USERS', 'ROLE_EDITOR_PAGE_USERS']. Then, if the administrator chooses to set the admin role to a user, then a prepared statement would add the default roles. Is this it? I'll explore the user provider, for now, I don't see how to exploit this yet. If you have an example, I'll take it.

Comment: I'd put all this logic into a Voter.

Answer (score 0):

I might have done something like this:

```
 /**
 * Get the permissions of the current user.
 *
 * @return array An array of permissions
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    // Get the user's role
    $role = $this->getRole();

    // If the user doesn't have a role defined, use the default role ROLE_USER
    if (!$role) {
        $role[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }

    // Get the permissions of the user's role
    $rolePermissions = $role->getPermissions();

    // Get the additional permissions of the user
    $userPermissions = $this->getUserPermissions();

    // Merge the role permissions and additional permissions using array_unique to avoid duplicates
    $permissions = array_unique(array_merge($rolePermissions, $userPermissions));

    return $permissions;
}

/**
 * Check if the current user has the given permission.
 *
 * @param string $permission The name of the permission to check
 * @return bool True if the user has the permission, false otherwise
 */
public function hasPermission(string $permission): bool
{
    // Get the user's permissions
    $permissions = $this->getRoles();

    // Check if the given permission is in the user's permissions array
    return in_array($permission, $permissions);
}

/**
 * Get the role object associated with the user.
 *
 * @return Role|null The role object, or null if no role is defined for the user
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role;
}

/**
 * Get the additional permissions of the user.
 *
 * @return array An array of permissions
 */
public function getUserPermissions()
{
    // Retrieve additional user permissions from the UserPermissions table
    $userPermissions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(UserPermissions::class)->findBy(['user' => $this]);

    // Transformation of Permission objects into an array of permission names
    $permissions = array_map(function ($permission) {
        return $permission->getName();
    }, $userPermissions);

    return $permissions;
}
```

And in role entity:

```
    /**
 * Get the permissions associated with the role.
 *
 * @return array An array of permissions
 */
public function getPermissions()
{
    // Retrieving role permissions from the RolePermissions table
    $rolePermissions = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(RolePermissions::class)->findBy(['role' => $this]);

    // Transformation of Permission objects into an array of permission names
    $permissions = array_map(function ($permission) {
        return $permission->getName();
    }, $rolePermissions);

    return $permissions;
}
```

I haven't tried it yet. But this is what I have in mind. And according to the documentation, my roles will start with ROLE_ as well as my permissions.
"The only rule is that every role must start with the ROLE_ prefix - otherwise, things won't work as expected. Other than that, a role is just a string and you can invent whatever you need (e.g. ROLE_PRODUCT_ADMIN)."
I'm going to sleep. I'll be back soon.